# Trocar subselect por join

Tags: sql-server, select, join, tsql

bom dia!

Já peço desculpa se explicação não ficar totalmente clara, é por que estou iniciando em SQL.

Como faço para substituir subselect por  algum tipo de join? Pois o subselect demora bem mais para carregar.

Exemplos:

A instrução abaixo está trazendo IDs (se repete) que contem registros de valor 123 na tabela A, mas somente de IDs que não contem 456 na mesma coluna da tabela B. (as tabelas são as mesmas)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID FROM BANCO..TABELA1 A
WHERE A.COLUNA1 = '123'
    AND A.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT B.ID FROM BANCO..TABELA1 B
            WHERE B.COLUNA1 = '456')
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte maneira, mas não funcionou

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID FROM PlanMisStg..TB_AUX_MOD_OFERTAS A
    LEFT JOIN PlanMisStg..TB_AUX_MOD_OFERTAS B
        ON A.TECNOLOGIA = B.TECNOLOGIA
            AND A.SEGMENTO = 'FTTH'
WHERE B.SEGMENTO NOT IN ('FTTH BENCH')
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

FELIPE, segue a ideia de como fazer o JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID FROM BANCO..TABELA1 A
JOIN TABELA1 B ON A.id = B.iD
WHERE A.COLUNA = '123' AND B.ID != 456
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA1 a
INNER JOIN TABELA2 b ON b.id = a.fk_coluna_com_a_chave_estrangeira
WHERE A.COLUNA = '123' AND B.ID != 456
ORDER BY A.ID
```

pra funcionar assim as duas tabelas tem que estar ligadas por chave estrangeiras aonde uma coluna de uma delas esta ligada ao id da outra.

Pode se inverter a ligacao como abaixo tambem

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA1 a
INNER JOIN TABELA2 b ON a.fk_coluna_com_a_chave_estrangeira = b.id 
WHERE A.COLUNA = '123' AND B.ID != 456
ORDER BY A.ID
```